# android realm @linkingObject return always null

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

i want to get the parent of specific object 
i have implemented this code

```
open class FicheX() : RealmObject(){
  var steps: RealmList<Etapex>? =RealmList()}
```

and in Etapex

```
@LinkingObjects("steps")
    val parent: RealmResults<FicheX>? = null
```

but I always get null inside parentFileOfSteps

Comment: Soooooo are you getting the object from Realm?

Comment: after inserting the hole object ficheX in realm and when I try to get etapes  with:  StepDataStore.getObject().query { equalTo("parent.id", id, Case.INSENSITIVE) } } the linking obj always null

Comment: What is `.query {`? This is not code from Realm

Comment: Oh, so it's from that unofficial ["Kotlin Realm Extension" thing](https://github.com/vicpinm/Kotlin-Realm-Extensions/blob/f05d18395e9c6fcf40c52fe76ecc159cd31dc6dd/library-base/src/main/java/com/vicpin/krealmextensions/RealmExtensions.kt#L24) that actually uses `copyFromRealm` for every single query, and you're left with unmanaged objects without even realizing it. Of course you get `null` from that. Use Realm's API instead.

Comment: ok thnx i will use  Realm's API